# Is there a way for the knights to be seated at a round table so that each knight sits near his friends?

Tags: c++, graph, cycle

I stumbled upon this problem while doing some coding challenges:

> The Round Table is located in a huge hall, rounded by N chairs. Each knight wants to sit near his friends, otherwise he refuses to sit.
> In the first line is given an integer number n, where n is the number of the Knights of the Round Table ( 3<=n<=100 ). The knights are numbered from 1 to n.
> Each of the following n lines contains a sequence of n values 0 or 1, separated by a space. The ith sequence shows the friendship relations of the ith knight. The jth value determines if the ith knight is a friend of the jth knight. They are friends if the value is 1, and not friends if the value is 0.
> Since friendship is reciprocal, if I is a friend of j, j is also friend of i.
> Output
> If the knights can be sit around the round table, show ‘YES’, otherwise show ‘NO’.

From what I understood, we are given an adjacency matrix of what is basically a undirected graph, where the nodes are the knights and the edges represent the friendship relations. Now my idea was to search for a cycle of length N in the graph, or a Hamiltonian Cycle. If that is the case, output YES, otherwise NO.

My code does work for the basic examples that are provided, but somehow it is failing at a certain test where N gets large enough. (Note that it is a wrong answer, not Time Limit error)

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

void dfs_search(vector<vector<int> > &matrix, vector<bool> &visited, int node, int parent, int n, int path, bool &found){
    if(found)
        return;
    else if(visited[node] && node == parent && path == n){
        found = 1;
        return;
    }
    else if(visited[node])
        return;
    else{
        visited[node] = 1;
        path++; 
        //cout<<node<<" "<<path<<endl;
        
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
            if(matrix[node][i] == 1){
                dfs_search(matrix, visited, i, parent, n, path, found);
            }
        }

        visited[node] = 0;
        path--;
    }

}
int main(){

    int n;

    cin >> n;

    bool found = 0;

    vector<vector<int> > matrix(n, vector<int>(n));
    vector<bool> visited(n, 0);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        dfs_search(matrix, visited, i, i, n, 0, found);
        if(found){
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(found)
        cout<<"YES";
    else
        cout<<"NO";

    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something completely obvious that would make my code fail with bigger input. Or am I missing any special case that needs to be handled?

I would appreciate any tip. Thanks in advance!

Example Input:

5
0 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 0

Example Output:

YES

Comment: Friends of my friends are my friends.:)

Comment: *Am I missing something completely obvious that would make my code fail with bigger input.* -- Code failing on bigger input happens when you actually run out of memory due to the larger input, or the recursion goes too deep.  Does your code exhibit any of those symptoms?  I bet not.  Why would, say a function, data structure, etc. work correctly for 50 items, but fail for 100 items?  It shouldn't fail, thus the issue shouldn't be with the size of the input, but a special case you are not handling correctly.

Comment: What does your code do if the given undirected graph contains multiple disconnected components?

Comment: @Ada it answers NO as it cannot find a cycle of length N

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, but do you have any idea of what that special case might be?

Comment: Could you link the coding challenge? I'd like to try my ideas on the input that causes the error

Comment: @Ada sadly it is an invite only challenge site from my university.

Comment: " sit near his friends"  What does this mean?  If friends must sit immediately adjacent, then you can immediately say NO if anyone has more than two friends.  Otherwise, you need to specify what exactly "near" means.

Comment: @ravenspoint seat near his friends mean that the corresponding knight must have a friendship relation with his adjacent neighbours. It doesn't mean that the knight must sit only between his friends

Comment: I think you mean that a knight refuses to sit unless *both* neighbors are among his friends.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Side note: you are looking for a cycle. So, without any loss, you can assume that the first seat is occupied by the first Knight. (`i = 0` in main loop).

Comment: The variable `found` is redundant.  Once `visited[node] && node == parent && path == n` is true, you are done.  Throw an exception and catch it in the main line to report success.  Your code will continue searching even after found is true.  ( If you want to avoid exceptions ( they freak some people ) then make found global so that all searches will stop after success.

Comment: I am surprised that you don't test the value of `found` after the internal recursive call to `dfs_search`, something like `if (found) return;`.

Comment: @ravenspoint thanks for your tip, I fixed the found as a global variable, the outcome is still the same however. Could it be possible that the input contains self loops? But still that should be avoided by the visited vector, shouldn't it?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what "near" actually means.

Comment: No idea what a 'self loop' is.  Best guess: you mean a cycle shorter than n.  The example you posted has such cycles.  Your code seems to handle them just fine.

Comment: Why are you calling `dfs_search` multiple times from `main`? If there's a Hamiltonian loop, you'll find it starting from any vertex; 0th is as good as any.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is best to use a standard library for your graph.  If you code a vertex and edge data structure from scratch every time, you will miss out on efficiencies and spend half your time debugging the graph structure, rather then your algorithm.

In general, I avoid using recursive functions, since they are not scalable to large graphs.  In this case a recursive function is very convenient for keeping track of the path length, so let's stick with that.  It is important to minimize the parameters to the recursive function, so as not to run out of stack memory.  So make the recursive function a class method and move as many parameters as possible to class attributes.

Like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "cGraph.h" // https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder

class cSeatFinder
{

public:
    void generateExample1();

    void arrangeSeating();

private:

    raven::graph::cGraph g;

    std::vector<bool> visited;

/**
 * @brief Determine if the there is a cycle that includes every node
 * 
 * @param node current node being explored
 * @param pathlength length of path to current node from start
 * 
 * Recursive.  Assumes starting node has id 0
 * 
 * If full cycle found, throws an exception std::runtime_error("found seating");
 * If not found, returns to caller
 */
    void dfs_full_cycle(
        int node,
        int pathlength);
};

void cSeatFinder::generateExample1()
{
    g.add(0, 1);
    g.add(0, 2);
    g.add(0, 4);
    g.add(1, 3);
    g.add(1, 4);
    g.add(2, 3);
    g.add(2, 4);
    g.add(3, 4);
}

void cSeatFinder::dfs_full_cycle(
    int node,
    int pathlength)
{

    // check if we have returned to the start
    if ( node == 0 ) {
        
        // check if we have visited every node
        if( pathlength == g.vertexCount()) {

            throw std::runtime_error("found seating");
        }
    }

    if (visited[node])
        return;

    visited[node] = 1;
    pathlength++;

    for (int vi : g.adjacentOut(node))
        dfs_full_cycle( vi, pathlength );

    visited[node] = 0;
    pathlength--;
}
void cSeatFinder::arrangeSeating()
{
    visited.resize(g.vertexCount(), false);
    try
    {
        dfs_full_cycle( 0, 0 );
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error &e)
    {
        if (e.what() == std::string("found seating"))
        {
            std::cout << "YES\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "NO\n";
}

main()
{
    cSeatFinder theSeatFinder;

    theSeatFinder.generateExample1();

    theSeatFinder.arrangeSeating();

    return 2;
}
```